# Pycharm: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils.cmd'

Tags: python, pip, pycharm, distutils

I'm trying to use opencv module with python.
I have Python3.10.

I installed the module and with the use of Python interpreter in the command line, writing "import cv2" it works fine.

Now, I want to use opencv inside PyCharm.
I went to "File->Settings->Project->Python Interpreter" and then I tried to add the module "opencv-python" but it returned:

```
"Error occurred when installing package 'opencv-python'. Details.."
```

and clicking on Details, this is the command output:

```
Error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/pycharm-community-2022.3.1/plugins/python-ce/helpers/packaging_tool.py", line 73, in run_pip
runpy.run_module(module_name, run_name='__main__', alter_sys=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 210, in run_module
return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name, mod_spec)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 97, in _run_module_code
_run_code(code, mod_globals, init_globals,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/home/user/Progetti/SottoProgettiPython/RiconoscimentoFacciale/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/__main__.py", line 29, in <module>
from pip._internal.cli.main import main as _main
  File "/home/user/Progetti/SottoProgettiPython/RiconoscimentoFacciale/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 9, in <module>
from pip._internal.cli.autocompletion import autocomplete
  File "/home/user/Progetti/SottoProgettiPython/RiconoscimentoFacciale/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/autocompletion.py", line 10, in <module>
from pip._internal.cli.main_parser import create_main_parser
  File "/home/user/Progetti/SottoProgettiPython/RiconoscimentoFacciale/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main_parser.py", line 9, in <module>
from pip._internal.build_env import get_runnable_pip
  File "/home/user/Progetti/SottoProgettiPython/RiconoscimentoFacciale/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/build_env.py", line 20, in <module>
from pip._internal.cli.spinners import open_spinner
  File "/home/user/Progetti/SottoProgettiPython/RiconoscimentoFacciale/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/spinners.py", line 9, in <module>
from pip._internal.utils.logging import get_indentation
  File "/home/user/Progetti/SottoProgettiPython/RiconoscimentoFacciale/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/utils/logging.py", line 29, in <module>
from pip._internal.utils.misc import ensure_dir
  File "/home/user/Progetti/SottoProgettiPython/RiconoscimentoFacciale/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/utils/misc.py", line 42, in <module>
from pip._internal.locations import get_major_minor_version
  File "/home/user/Progetti/SottoProgettiPython/RiconoscimentoFacciale/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/locations/__init__.py", line 67, in <module>
from . import _distutils
  File "/home/user/Progetti/SottoProgettiPython/RiconoscimentoFacciale/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/locations/_distutils.py", line 20, in <module>
from distutils.cmd import Command as DistutilsCommand

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils.cmd'
```

I didn't found any working solutions for the module distutils.

I tried to install and reinstall the module "python3.10-distutils" but it is already installed.

Someone knows how to solve the problem?
Thanks in advance,

Marco

Comment: You may have installed `python3.10-disutils` for the Python 3.10 system interpreter, but you're not using that system interpreter. You're using a Python 3.9 installation at `/usr/lib/python3.9`

Comment: Check if you have any other Python interpreters configured in PyCharm, and try using a different interpreter